# How do I make user authentication api for laravel

Tags: api, authentication, laravel-5

I tried this using jwt-auth, but the thing is token gets expired. I want to remember the user with token that never gets expired. Is their any possible way to do it in Laravel 5.2.
Should I send email and password for each request to api instead of saving session and token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will implement this way:
If the user selects **Remember me**, set the `ttl` to a longer time ,say 1 year OR month. To do this we need to publish

```
 php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"
```

Then we can override the default `ttl` value which is 60 mins to our desired value.

```
 $jwt = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::get('jwt');
 $jwt['ttl'] = 60*24*30; // 30 days
 \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::set('jwt',$jwt);
```

Hope this helps!